# 'xterm-256color': unknown terminal type

Tags: macos, terminal, terminfo

when I type the clear command at my mac osx terminal I receive the following error:

'xterm-256color': unknown terminal type.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to work... Possibilities include:

- conflicting environment variable definitions for `TERMINFO` or `TERMINFO_DIRS`
- The specific files needed are removed.

OSX has bundled ncurses for several years, and a default configuration "just works".  Your terminal database would be in `/usr/share/terminfo/`
while some packages may also use `/opt/local/share/terminfo`.